# "Profitable" or "Affordable"

Tags: word-choice

Trying to create a tagline, but unsure as to which word will entice a person more :

**Profitable or Affordable**?

The context being: _________ Barcode Scanning

If I were to use both what order should I put the words in?

Comment: Why not use both?

Comment: @IanMacDonald that's actually pretty good idea. Was thinking it may be a little too long in that case.

Comment: "Profitable" means something completely different to "affordable". Which is more enticing is a matter of psychology rather than English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the word you want is **Affordable**, i.e. the barcode scanning technology is not expensive.

While it not being expensive may help with one's bottom line, it's hard to see the barcode scanners themselves generating profit. "Our affordable barcode scanning system will help make your company more profitable" makes sense, but "Our profitable barcode scanning systemm"??? That would only seem to make sense were I selling a barcode scanning system for a profit.

Answer (score 0):

Marketing has its own rules that don't necessarily play by English grammar. I'm putting "Affordable" first because I think that's more important for the market I perceive you reaching (small businesses). I think, in this case, the biggest selling points should be at either end.

You could do the following:

> Affordable Profitable Barcode Scanning

It isn't a complete sentence, so there aren't a lot of rules to worry about. I think the following might read better.

> Affordable. Profitable. Barcode Scanning.

or

> Affordable — Profitable — Barcode Scanning

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends which side of the scan you're on. Are you charging/benefiting? In this case I'd use "affordable."